# deployed pb App transaction not connected

Tags: runtime, powerbuilder

I have deployed a PB App created with PB12.5 Classic. Its a PB winform app. I have managed to deployed it on a test unit to test its performance. I have created a custom runtime packager.
this runtime packager that i have created consists of basic PB runtime DLL, which is the PBDWE125.dll, PBSHR125.dll PBSNC125.dll, PBVM125.dll as per sybase's instruction in infocenter.sybase.com.

i have also packaged microsoft dlls which is the atl71.dll, libjcc.dll, libjtml.dll, msvcp71.dll, msvcp100.dll, msvcr71.dll, msvcr100.dll and nlwnsck.dll.

all of these dlls are installed in C:\Program Files\Sybase\Shared\PowerBuilder.

my problem is, my PB app is running BUT WHEN I TRY TO ESTABLISH CONNECTION my database server it prompt "Transaction not Connected"

is it the PBSNC problem? i tried registering it using regsvr32 and it didnt work. i have used PB runtime packager but still no luck. i have tried the app path registry and link it to the directory stated above and still no luck...

my question is

1. is there anything that i can do to make this work?
2. win 7 has c++ runtime libraries installed already right?
3. what can be the cause of "transaction not connected" error
4. what can i do to make it work?

note:

1. i have user access to the database server
2. i can access the database server
3. the app is working when the PB IDE is installed

please enlighten me! thank you :D

Comment: What is the code you use to establish the connection?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does the computer that the app is deployed to have the SQL Server Native Client runtime installed? (I'm assuming you're using SQL Server because you mention PBSNC125.dll.) Here's some info from a [blog post](http://slapouttech.blogspot.com/2012/04/powerbuilder-and-sql-server-tips-on.html) I wrote a while back (I was using PB 12 and SQL Server 2008, so things may be different for you.)

> **Files Required**
>
> On your client machines, in addition to the PB runtimes (including PBSNC120.dll, which is for SQL Server), you also need to install the [SQL Server Native Client runtime](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=16978). These come as an msi installer package from Microsoft. When you install the SQL Server client, you'll need to do so as an administrator. Otherwise you'll get a cryptic error message along the lines of "0: -1".
>
> There's a [32-bit](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=188400&clcid=0x409) and a [64-bit](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=188401&clcid=0x409) version of the runtime. The 64-bit version won't run on a 32-bit version of Windows and vice versa.
>
> Footnote: My project used PowerBuilder Classic version 12.1 and SQL Server 2008

Answer (score 0):

"Transaction not connected" usually comes from a DataWindow being given a transaction object that isn't connected to the database. It sounds like there isn't much error trapping when you connect to the database, and you're getting a down stream symptom. You need to add error checking to your CONNECT routine, and that will give you more clues as to what is going on.

One of the more common problems with connections on deployment is when programs try to read connection parameters from an INI file, and on deployment the app can't find the INI file, so with no error checking on reading the INI, the program is trying to connect with an empty transaction object and fails. However, the information you've given us is too late to have any clues whether that is the problem or not.